# SystemJS import without transpiling

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, aurelia, systemjs

I have a script that I need to import which I cannot have wrapped in a System.register call.

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could tell babel to ignore the module:

**config.js**

```js
System.config({
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: "babel",
  babelOptions: {
    "ignore": [
      "github:*",
      "npm:*",
      "my/module/that/i/do/not/want/transpiled.js"
    ],
    ...
```

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for or whether the `.js` is needed.

Answer (score 1):

you can import the script using `Globals`

[systemjs globals](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/module-formats.md#globals)

> The global format loads globals identically to if they were included via script tags but with some extra features including the ability to shim dependencies, set custom globals, and define the exports of the global module.